# How to get candle low and high of a specific candle in 3 mins tf?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I just want 10:00 am candle low and high 10:15 AM candle low and high. And see which low is lowest and which high is the highest, plot only those 2. But this code is not doing that. Can anyone help me?

I am using 3m tf.

```
indicator("opentime",  shorttitle="OPENTIME", overlay=true)

interval = input.string(title="Duration :", options=["1000-1015"], defval="1000-1015")

new_bar(x)=>
    y= ta.change(time(x))!=0

var dh_snap=high
var dl_snap=low
var d_open = open
var running_max=high
var running_min=low

mark_ = new_bar("D")

session_check = na(time("3", interval))

if mark_
    running_max := high
    running_min := low

running_max := math.max(running_max,high)
running_min := math.min(running_min,low)

if session_check and not(session_check[1])
    dh_snap:= running_max
    dl_snap:= running_min

plot(dh_snap, color=color.new(#801922, 10), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_cross, trackprice=true)
plot(dl_snap, color=color.new(#008000, 10), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_cross, trackprice=true)
```

This code giving range low and high at the time. How can I tweak this to get what I want? also I want it to plot for current day session, no need it for past trading days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hour` and `minute` built-in variables to figure out the time. Then use a `var` to store the low and high values.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var float ten_low = na
var float fifteen_high = na

is_ten = (hour == 10) and (minute == 0)
is_fifteen = (hour == 10) and (minute == 15)

ten_low := is_ten ? low : ten_low    // Get the new low if it is 10:00, keep the old value otherwise
fifteen_high := is_fifteen ? high : fifteen_high    // Get the new high if it is 10:15, keep the old value otherwise

running_max = math.max(ten_low, fifteen_high)
running_min = math.min(ten_low, fifteen_high)

plot(ten_low, "10:00 Low", color=color.orange)
plot(fifteen_high, "10:15 High", color=color.olive)
plot(running_max, "Running Max", color=color.green)
plot(running_min, "Running Min", color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found better way of doing this. Instead of using time, we can just go to the bar directly by its number. So first set your timeframe of desired, then look up which bar you want to get values off. Here is how I solved it.

```
//@version=5

indicator("opentime",  shorttitle="OPENTIME", overlay=true)

import PineCoders/VisibleChart/3 as ch

var lines = array.new_line()
var labels = array.new_label()
var barnum = 0
var _low = low
var _high = high

if session.isfirstbar
    barnum := bar_index
if barstate.isconfirmed and bar_index == barnum + 11
    _low := low
    _high := high

if barstate.isconfirmed and bar_index == barnum + 17
    _low := math.min(low, _low)
    _high := math.max(high, _high)

rightmost_bar = ch.rightBarIndex()

// clear labels
for lb in labels
    label.delete(lb)
    
// clear lines
for ln in lines
    line.delete(ln)

array.clear(lines)
array.clear(labels)

array.push(lines, line.new(bar_index - 1, _low, bar_index, _low, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(#8f9197, 1), width=1))
array.push(labels, label.new(rightmost_bar - 1, _low, text="Low: " + str.tostring(_low), color=color.new(#F5F5EC,1), style=label.style_label_upper_right, textalign=text.align_right))

array.push(lines, line.new(bar_index - 1, _high, bar_index, _high, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(#8f9197, 1), width=1))
array.push(labels, label.new(rightmost_bar - 1, _high, text="High: " + str.tostring(_high), color=color.new(#F5F5EC,1), style=label.style_label_upper_right, textalign=text.align_right))
```